# If statement trouble

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd, command

Not entirely sure if the IF statement works properly. I want it to identify if Desktop.ini exists, if it has the right attributes to be re-written and then reset the attributes.

Does this IF statement do what I want it to? As sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't whether I have the IF / IF not regardless. I think I need to check whether the file exists first but I am unsure how.

```
@ECHO OFF

attrib +s "%CD%"
set ICODIR=%CD%\Icon\

for %%F in ("%ICODIR%"*.ico) do set ICO=%%~nxF
echo %ICO%
echo %ICO:~0,-4%

set ICOINI=Desktop.ini
if exist %ICOINI% attrib -s -h %ICOINI%

echo [.ShellClassInfo] > %ICOINI%
echo IconResource=%ICODIR:~2%%ICO%>>%ICOINI%
echo InfoTip=%ICO:~0,-4%>>%ICOINI%

if not "%2"=="" (
    echo FolderType=%2 >> %ICOINI%
)

attrib -a +s +h %ICOINI%

Pause
```

The code without the if statement.

```
@ECHO OFF

attrib +s "%CD%"
set ICODIR=%CD%\Icon\

for %%F in ("%ICODIR%"*.ico) do set ICO=%%~nxF
echo %ICO%
echo %ICO:~0,-4%

set ICOINI=Desktop.ini
attrib -s -h %ICOINI%

echo [.ShellClassInfo] > %ICOINI%
echo IconResource=%ICODIR:~2%%ICO%>>%ICOINI%
echo InfoTip=%ICO:~0,-4%>>%ICOINI%

attrib -a +s +h %ICOINI%

Pause
```

EDIT: It seems the reason it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't is more to do with Windows than the batch file. As if I delete a file within the folder it will work, no wonder I couldn't find the fault >.<

Comment: What exactly is the question you're asking us? I don't see one here. What trouble are you having?

Comment: I want to know if the IF statement if screwing up the batch file. Sometimes it recreates the icon for the folder, sometimes it creates the folder icon but only small when viewing the folder properties, sometimes it does nothing. I don't know why and I want to know if it is the IF statement, Windows or the code I have written.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide that information there, where people can see it. You *still* have not asked a question, so when you make your edit please do so. This is a question and answer site, and in order to get an answer you must first ask a question. :-) You'll need to be specific about it - a question like "Does my IF statement work right?" isn't a proper question here.

Comment: You're right, I merely stated what I wanted to know! Not technically a question... I stated what I think the problem is, and also stated that I wanted to know if what I thought was the problem.

Comment: I've asked twice for you to [edit] and provide the **specific** problem you're having, and ask a **specific** question. You haven't done either of those things. **Describe what the problem is you're trying to solve, and ask a specific question**. "Does this look right to you?" is not a valid question, and you haven't clearly described a problem here.

Comment: I don't know who is having problems, you or I. I stated I don't know what the problem is. The question is, is there an obvious problem which I do not understand / see located within the IF / IF NOT statements. Two lines is VERY specific and I cannot get more specific. I also cannot ask the question more specifically as I DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHETHER IT IS A PROBLEM OR NOT HENCE ME ASKING THE QUESTION TO KNOW WHETHER IT IS A PROBLEM FROM WHAT I WANT IT TO DO. I am not very adept nor very knowledgeable in batch file programming. If I were, I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: The question you asked was "Does this IF statement do what I want it to?", which you can clearly answer yourself. (It either does what you want it to or it doesn't, and you can figure that out, right?) PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT AT ME. I'm trying to help you ask your question so that it doesn't get closed as "not a real question", and so that you'll get an answer. I've explained several times now what the issue is with what you've posted. As you seem to just want to leave it the way it is, and START SHOUTING when I try to help, I'll just vote to close it and stop bothering you. Good luck.

Comment: You know what, you're right. I guess I knew the answer before I asked it. I just like looking stupid! When I ask for help I just want you to patronise me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get an idea what parameters you are passing in.  Your problems could be caused by a number of things.

1. You may have spaces or special characters in your input parameters.
2. If you 'Run as Admin' the Current Directory will be changed and will not be what you think it is.
3. Does ICODIR contain spaces?

I modified your code below to

1. Add some debugging code
2. Change quotes around %ICODIR%*.ico
3. Handle %2 properly (or maybe not... not sure if you should have quotes in what you echo)

`

```
@ECHO OFF
echo.1=%1
echo.2=%2
echo.CD=%CD%

attrib +s "%CD%"
set ICODIR=%CD%\Icon\

for %%F in ("%ICODIR%*.ico") do set ICO=%%~nxF
echo %ICO%
echo %ICO:~0,-4%

set ICOINI=Desktop.ini
if exist %ICOINI% attrib -s -h %ICOINI%

echo [.ShellClassInfo] > %ICOINI%
echo IconResource=%ICODIR:~2%%ICO%>>%ICOINI%
echo InfoTip=%ICO:~0,-4%>>%ICOINI%

if not "%~2"=="" (
    echo FolderType=%~2 >> %ICOINI%
)

echo.ICOINI=%ICOINI%
attrib -a +s +h %ICOINI%

Pause
```

Comment: change `"%2"` to `"%~2"` for a more robust compare.

Comment: Yes... Thank you foxidrive for pointing that out.  I intended to do that.  I edited the code above.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your 2nd parameter. Try:

```
 if not "%~2"=="" (
    echo FolderType=%2 >> %ICOINI%
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I wasn't sure of that myself. What would %~2 change? I am thinking there isn't any need for this is statement at all, as I create the Desktop.ini anyway, do you think I need it?

Comment: batch parameters may have double quotes and whitespace, if so you should use it so: `"%~1"`. The tilde removes double quotes so you can save add it again. I don't know, `if`  you _need_ this statement to get your .ini working.

Comment: It appears that I need some sort of check. I have tried taking the if statement out and it has the same effect of sometimes creating the folder icon, sometimes not. When I take out the if / if not then it says 'Desktop.ini' does not exist when run the first time (I have added the code without the IF / IF not)

Comment: if you remove the `if`  statement completely, the `foldertype`  will not be written.

Comment: I guess I do not need it to echo FolderType at all. I just need an if statement to check if Desktop.ini exists and if not, to create one. How could I do that?

**if not exist %ICOINI%
echo something>>%ICOINI%
attrib -s -h %ICOINI%**

Would that fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The only question you have asked is `Does this IF statement do what I want it to?`

The answer is obvious.  **NO**

If it did, you wouldn't be asking that question.

Comment: It is not obvious, it could be many things going wrong that I have no idea about. It may be OBVIOUS to you but that is no reason to patronise and humiliate other people asking for help. Thanks for making me feel about two inches tall.

Comment: As I previously mentioned to Ken White, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I have NO idea why, literally NONE, it may seem stupid, you may think I am thick as two short planks, I don't care how retarded you think I, or my question is, but thanks for an honest answer at least. N.B/ The batch also sometimes works without the if statement, sometimes not. So I am trying to determine where the error is coming from.